# One to Many remove Object not deleting object on many entity

Tags: ios, core-data

I have one entity called `Activity` (one) and `Game` (many).  I setup the delete rule as Cascade for the "game" relationships on the `Activity` entity and Nullify (*** more on this later) for the "activity" relationships on the Game entity.

If I delete an `Activity` object, then all `Game` objects would also be deleted from core data.  So the cascade rule for that relationship seemed to be working fine.

Now, if I delete one or all of the the many objects "Game" using either provided methods: `removeGameObject`: and `removeGame`:, that `Activity` object would no longer be linked to any `Game` objects.  So that seemed to work.  But upon doing an independent query the "Game" entity, those supposed to be removed Game objects were still in Core Data.  They are not just being linked to any `Activity` object.

*** I have also tried No Action, Cascade deleting rule as well.

I can manually remove the Game object(s).  But there must be a right way to do this.

Any pointers?

```
@class Game;

@interface Activity : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * activityID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * activityType;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *game;
@end

@interface Activity (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addGameObject:(Game *)value;
- (void)removeGameObject:(Game *)value;
- (void)addGame:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeGame:(NSSet *)values;

@end

@class Activity;

@interface Game : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Activity *activity;

@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`removeGame` and `removeGameObject` are methods on the `Activity` entity, so why would you think that they would delete a `Game` object?  They do exactly what they say, the remove the `Game` from this `Activity` - removing the reference, but they don't actually delete the `Game` object.  These methods are a little more useful where you have a to-many rather than a to-one relationship as they allow you to easily remove a particular object from the relationship.

If you want to delete the `Game` entity then you need to call the `deleteObject:` method on your `NSManagedObjectContext` instance, specifying the `Game` that you want to delete.  If you do this and you have set the delete rule to `Nullify` on the inverse relationship from `Game` to `Activity` then the reference to the `Game` will be removed from the `Activity`.